# Layout inflated RecyclerView onBindViewHolder not being called unless I manually scrolldown

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView inside a programmatically inflated layout

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_print, frameLayout, false);
        frameLayout.addView(view);
        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                initRecyclerView(recyclerView);

            }
        });
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="1200px"
    android:layout_height="1920px"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appointmentName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However the RecyclerView's `onBindViewHolder` is not being called unless I manually scrolldown. Why does this happen and how can I make it automatically display the data?

**Edit1:_______________________________**

I need the viewTreeObserver because if I try to perform a calculation on the `View` without it, it throws the error: `width and height must be > 0`

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Doing it without the `onGlobalLayout` throws an error:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_print, frameLayout, false);
        frameLayout.addView(view);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        photoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(this, listPhotos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(photoAdapter);
        int spacing = SpacingUtil.convertIntToDP(this, GRID_VIEW_SPACING);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(GRID_VIEW_COLUMN_COUNT, spacing, false));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, GRID_VIEW_COLUMN_COUNT));


        listPhotos.add(new Card("https://i.imgur.com/rC6cM10.png", "image1"));
        listPhotos.add(new Card("https://i.imgur.com/JR5rf1J.png", "image2"));
        listPhotos.add(new Card("https://i.imgur.com/mTsS11e.png", "image3"));

        photoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(view); <---------- The error is thrown here
```

Comment: This is because you are calling it inside the viewtree observer.
Can you tell me your use case so that i can assist you better approach for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only do the thing you absolutely need in onGlobalLayout - i.e., the bitmap stuff.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
photoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(this, listPhotos);
recyclerView.setAdapter(photoAdapter);
int spacing = SpacingUtil.convertIntToDP(this, GRID_VIEW_SPACING);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(GRID_VIEW_COLUMN_COUNT, spacing, false));
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, GRID_VIEW_COLUMN_COUNT));


listPhotos.add(new Card("https://i.imgur.com/rC6cM10.png", "image1"));
listPhotos.add(new Card("https://i.imgur.com/JR5rf1J.png", "image2"));
listPhotos.add(new Card("https://i.imgur.com/mTsS11e.png", "image3"));

photoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(view);
    }
});
```

Comment: because I'm doing a calculation with the inflated view height of the recyclerview and without that listener it returns 0 if I call ```Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + view.getHeight());``` right under ```frameLayout.addView(view);```

Comment: after I add the recyclerview and load the data, I try to convert the entire view into a bitmap. (I added my code above) and the conversion to bitmap throws ```width and height must be > 0``` without the viewTreeObserver

Comment: this creates a bit of a race condition because once the ```View``` is created, the method ```loadBitmapFromView(view)``` is called and converts the view to a bitmap. But there is a chance that the ```RecyclerView``` hasn't finished loading the images with ```Glide```. So the bitmap maybe missing images.

Comment: it works when I delay it for 5 seconds using a handler, but not with the viewtree observer. anyways I marked your answer as correct since it answered the original question. Thanks a bunch for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: "But there is a chance that the RecyclerView hasn't finished loading the images with Glide. So the bitmap maybe missing images." -> Glide allows you to set a callback that will be invoked when the image is done loading. Add a callback and do your bitmap stuff there.

Comment: Yeah it turned out to be an issue with glide. https://pastebin.com/6KG661LR. ```imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);``` loads the bitmap into the imageView in the ```onGlobalLayout```, but using Glide doesn't